# Does krias hatorah have to be heard in order?

Tags: torah-reading, minyan

Suppose I came to shul late and heard the last aliyah, then I catch kriah again with another minyan. Would I need to hear the last aliyah again or does the first time suffice?

Comment: It's apparently a machloket rishonim (possibly two girsas in masechet sofrim) http://www.hakirah.org/Vol31Ariel.pdf